# How to Enable Listview scrolling that disabled in TabBarView parent

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

ListView class is a scrollable list of widgets. I disabled horizontal scroll in the parent of ListView class and affected in the child(ListView class) by this code:

```
new Stack(
    ...,
    children: <Widget>[
        ...,
        new TabBarView(
            ...,
            children: icons.map((Icon icon) {
                ...,
                return new Container(
                    ...,
                    child:new Card(
                        ...,
                        child: new Stack(
                            ...,
                            children: <Widget>[
                                ...,
                                new Container(
                                    ...,
                                    new ListView(// enable scrolling here
                                        ...
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                            ...
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            }).toList()
        ),
        new GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        ),
    ],
),
```

Now I want to use scrolling in the inner ListView class that I commented it in the code.

Comment: Uh so ListView always scrolls - that's what it's meant for. Unless you've put the GestureDetector in a widget that covering the TabBarView (it's not clear from your example), in which case you've effectively blocked all touch events from reaching your list view and therefore even though it still can scroll it won't ever actually get the touch events it needs to do so. Depending on what your code actually looks like it might be as simple as setting the GestureDetector behaviour to HitTestBehaviour.translucent.

Comment: Can you give an actual example ? What you are requesting is not possible. That's the whole point of `HitTestBehavior.opaque`.